# Is it possible to establish P2P connection between android and iPhone?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wifi-direct

I have heard a lot about P2P connection with upcoming iOS8 via WiFi direct. But, also heard, its yet not possible to make any P2P connection between an iPhone and android Phone. Anybody has tried?

Also, is it possible to transfer JSON and Meta Data using WiFi Direct?

Thanks

Comment: If you have both kind of devices you can find out in minutes. What did you try? You can do the same using wifi or wifi direct. So indeed exchange all kind of data. Server/client apps that work with wifi can also be used with wifi direct.

Comment: I tried with iOS7, iPhone 5S. It was not possible.

Comment: Could not make connectiomn ws coming up and  heard, its yet not possible to make any P2P connection between an iPhone and android Phone.